# How to solve the following sequence limit:

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits-without-lhopital

> Find $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n$  where $$ a_n=\Bigg(\frac{3n^2}{3n^2-1}\Bigg)^{2n^2+3}$$

How to even start with an exponent problem like this ?

Comment: But you posted another limit problem a few _minutes_ before this!

Comment: Yes, probably this guy is facing difficulties to solve limit problems lol

Comment: Please provide more context: Where did it come from? What have you learned so far? Any possible conclusions that you feel that would work here? Any similar examples you have seen in your course for you to imitate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint :** Take logarithm both side and then take $n \to \infty$